# Select em uma data e o retorno não pode ser null

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird

Preciso que o retorno de uma data, caso ela esteja "Null" no BD retorne outra data ou outro dado que não seja "Null".

Comment: Por favor, leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/75104), [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e [Seja mais específico na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atribua o `IS NOT NULL` pois irá filtrar todos os valores que não são NULL.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DataInicio IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
select case
         when campo_que_pode_estar_null is null then 'valor retornado se estiver null'
       else
         campo_que_pode_estar_null
       end 
from tabela
```

Com isso, mesmo que o campo esteja null, te retornará algo.

Answer (score -1):

Esqueci de comentar que o banco de dados era Firebird.

Mas achei uma solução, utilizei o `coalesce('nomedacoluna',0 ou'') as 'nomedacoluna'`

Comment: Luis edite sua pergunta com esse detalhe, não use o campo de resposta para se corrigir. Aconselho que apaga essa resposta e Edite sua pergunta